# matching an object with its corresponding value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

Here is the problem...

> Create a function called keyAccessor. keyAccessor should take  in two
>   parameters: an array of people, and an object.  Each person's name is
>   also a property on an object.  keyAccessor should loop through the
>   array of names, and   access corresponding values for each name in the
>   object,   pushing the values into an empty array.   keyAccessor should
>   return the new array.

Example set of names that could be passed in

```
var names = ["Dan", "Todd", "Andrew", "Doug"]
```

Example object that could be passed in

```
var people = {
  Dan: { city: "Las Vegas", age: 24 },
  Todd: { city: "France", age: 28 },
  Andrew: { city: "Portland", age: 12 },
  Doug: { city: "New New York", age: 56 },
}
```

Example new array that would be returned

```
var sampleOutput = [
  { city: "Las Vegas", age: 24 },
  { city: "France", age: 28 },
  { city: "Portland", age: 12 },
  { city: "New New York", age: 56 }
]
```

This is how far I have got.

```js
function keyAccessor(arr, obj){
  var newArr = []
  console.log(obj)
  console.log(arr)
  for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]=obj.name){
      return newArr.push(obj)
    }
  }

  return newArr
}
```

Comment: Equality checks in JS use `==` for loose comparison and `===` for strict comparison. Plain `=` is an assignment. I'm talking about that `if` instead of your loop. That's just one of your problems though.

Comment: This sounds like a coding test...

Comment: Tip: I think you only need one "return" from the function

Comment: it is a test, but i am allowed to use what ever resources i want

Comment: Perhaps the .map function can help you.

Comment: Another tip is, before using a for loop, or any loop. Try apply `map`, `filter`, `reduce` first. These builtin array functions are more efficient. `Object.keys(people)` will return an array of keys, `Object.values(people)` will return an array of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this question is really simple, you probably don't need a standalone function.
Using `map` should be enough.

```js
const names = ["Todd", "Dan", "Andrew", "Doug"];
const people = {
  Dan: { city: "Las Vegas", age: 24 },
  Todd: { city: "France", age: 28 },
  Andrew: { city: "Portland", age: 12 },
  Doug: { city: "New New York", age: 56 },
};

function keyAccessor(names, people) {
  return names.map(name => people[name]);
}

console.log(keyAccessor(names, people));
```

The code above equivalents to:

```js
let result = [];
for(let index in names) {  // in this case, index will be 1, 2, 3, 4
  let name = names[index];
  result.push(people[name]);
}
```

`names.map(name => people[name]);` is shorthand for `names.map(name => { return (people[name]); });`
Since the name is the key for people object, `people.Dan` and `people['Dan']` will return same result.

Comment: this did work, I understand .map, but could you clarify a little but what exactly is going on. If I'm correct you map through names and set a new array called name that takes in each person in the object people?

Comment: I wrote a lil bit more to explain this. Hope it could help